# Creating XML Banking document from template

Tags: c#, xml

I have this template from a bank that is used to make payments on bank account transfers.

See xml below. I have included the sample data that has to be entered when sending the file to the bank.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>Cart Urgent28052018_57894</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2018-06-29T11:52:23</CreDtTm>
      <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>667896.00</CtrlSum>
      <InitgPty>
        <Nm>CART LIMITED</Nm>
        <Id>
          <OrgId>
            <Othr>
              <Id>S001234/PJones</Id>
              <SchmeNm>
                <Cd>CUST</Cd>
              </SchmeNm>
            </Othr>
          </OrgId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId>Payment for addon development SAP B1</PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
      <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
      <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>667896.00</CtrlSum>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <InstrPrty>HIGH</InstrPrty>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <ReqdExctnDt>2018-06-29</ReqdExctnDt>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>CART LIMITED</Nm>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>0112345110846</Id>
          </Othr>
        </Id>
        <Ccy>KES</Ccy>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>SBICKENX</BIC>
         </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <PmtId>
          <EndToEndId>156335578965</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <Amt>
          <InstdAmt Ccy="KES">667896.00</InstdAmt>
        </Amt>
        <ChrgBr>DEBT</ChrgBr>
        <CdtrAgt>
          <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>DTKEKENA</BIC>
            <ClrSysMmbId>
              <MmbId>63000</MmbId>
            </ClrSysMmbId>
          </FinInstnId>
        </CdtrAgt>
        <Cdtr>
          <Nm>EOH SEAL LTD</Nm>
          <PstlAdr>
            <StrtNm>P.O. Box 10496</StrtNm>
            <TwnNm>Nairobi</TwnNm>
            <Ctry>KE</Ctry>
            <AdrLine>P.O. Box 10496</AdrLine>
            <AdrLine>00100 NAIROBI</AdrLine>
          </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
          <Id>
            <Othr>
              <Id>0112406001</Id>
            </Othr>
          </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
        <RmtInf>
          <Ustrd>Cart Urgent28052018_57894</Ustrd>
        </RmtInf>
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

The file is quite long as has to be in the format given. The black letters represent the details to be passed to the xml. To test if I understood what data goes where I filled it manually and sent to bank for testing. That is all good now.

I have a SAP addon program that captures details from a form and generates a list. Each payment must follow this structure.

Looking at the below:

```
<Nm>CART LIMITED</Nm>
<Id>
  <OrgId>
    <Othr>
      <Id>S001234/PJones</Id>
      <SchmeNm>
        <Cd>CUST</Cd>
      </SchmeNm>
    </Othr>
  </OrgId>
</Id>
```

Is creating a class with all properties according to the template the best way to create the xml needed.

How do I stagger the

```
<Id>
   <OrgId>
      <Othr>
```

as in the case above?

Also the `<CtrlSum>667896.00</CtrlSum>` is found in the group header and payment info tags. How do I deal with this?

Comment: "Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes" in Visual Studio, then populate and serialize those classes using XmlSerializer. Read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: Had been wondering whether there was a tool for this, however, the class generated is so long and ugly that I may have to generate one myself. Like in the question, the .xml is a bit complex.

Comment: See above, edited.

Comment: sorry can you be a bit clear of what is exactly the problem? and also can you put another example with more data? like 3 payment methods

Comment: Okay, let me explain my main problem. I have not worked with XML very much. I have created a SAP form where users will enter the data required above in text fields. The xml file I have posted is what the bank needs in that exact structure. I tried "Paste XML As Classes" in Visual Studio to develop a class I could use. I would then want to create and populate a list based on this class. However what VS produces seems not to be very helpful. So basically how do I best transform data from a form and then output an xml file as above?

Comment: but why the VS result is not helpful? remember you need to parse the XML and create a base class one time, so you can create using the visual studio and edit to get exactly what you wont. if you feel the VS is creating a class to different what you want, you can also use an online tool like https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net , in internet are too many, just need to pass a valid XML structure

Comment: just one more think, Independent what you use to get the C# class you need to pass a good XML Template, you say something about list, and in you XML template you dont have nothing to create a list, to make the list you need to have for example 3 node of payment method

Comment: Yes, the form has a matrix with rows for multiple payments. That is what the list is for.

Comment: For the XML part, the simplest and most easiest solution would be to create multiple POCO classes, use DataAnotation to arrange the output of the XML file, set the values  through the classes and then serialize....that simple

Comment: I have already created the multiple POCO classes and set values. Let me look at data anotation to arrange the output of my xml

Comment: Finally resolved this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For what i see, the problem is you have a addon in SAP to specify multiple payments methods, but in the XML template given from the bank you don't the structure for multiple payments, so you need to get this information to know how can you work with it.

when you have this information you can use a better XML template with VS or another tool to generate the correct class to work with the XML